# error 'datetime' is not defined when importing module

Tags: python, datetime

Beginner in python and getting a datetime error. Not sure why. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have 2 .py files in the same directory, model.py and func2.py. I am trying to import func.py when running model.py. Error i am getting is **NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined**

**model.py:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
import func2

def data_upload(xls):
    demand_df=pd.read_excel(xls,'Historical Demand',encoding = "ISO-8859-1",parse_dates=['Transaction Date'],converters={'Part Number':str})
    po_df=pd.read_excel(xls,'Historical PO',encoding = "ISO-8859-1",parse_dates=['Date Order Placed', 'Date Order Received'],converters={'Part Number':str, 'Unit Cost':float,'Total Spend':float})
    snapshot_df=pd.read_excel(xls,'Snapshot Summary',converters={'Part Number':str},)
    other_df=pd.read_excel(xls,'Other Data',converters={'Part Number':str})
    return demand_df, po_df, snapshot_df, snapshot_df, other_df

xls = pd.ExcelFile('/Users/Desktop/Input Raw Data Template.xlsx')

demand_df, po_df, snapshot_df, snapshot_df, other_df = data_upload(xls)

input_scope = 365
input_leadtime_max = 140

model_input_df = func2.scoping_analysis(demand_df,po_df,input_scope)
```

**func2.py:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def scoping_analysis(demand_df,po_df,input_scope):
    demand_scope = []
    demand_timeframe = demand_df['Transaction Date']> demand_df['Transaction Date'].max() - datetime.timedelta(days=input_scope)
    demand_df = demand_df[demand_timeframe].groupby('Part Number').sum().astype(int)
    demand_df = demand_df[demand_df['Transaction Quantity']>0].sort_values('Transaction Quantity',ascending=False)
    demand_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    demand_scope = demand_df['Part Number'].values

    po_scope = []
    po_timeframe = po_df['Date Order Placed']> po_df['Date Order Placed'].max() - datetime.timedelta(days=input_scope)  
    po_df = po_df[po_timeframe].groupby('Part Number').sum().astype(int)
    po_df = po_df[po_df['Total Spend']>0].sort_values('Total Spend',ascending=False)
    po_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    po_scope = po_df['Part Number'].values

    inscope_items = list(set(demand_scope).intersection(po_scope))

    model_input_df = pd.DataFrame(data = inscope_items, columns=['Part Number'])

    return model_input_df
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-3db20f4cbfba> in <module>()
----> 1 model_input_df = func2.scoping_analysis(demand_df,po_df,input_scope)
      2 


~/Desktop/Programming/Code/SPO/func2.py in scoping_analysis(demand_df, po_df, input_scope)
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import datetime
      4 
      5 def scoping_analysis(demand_df,po_df,input_scope):

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

Comment: Could you include the full traceback in the question?

Comment: I would say it's raised in line read_excel because of "parse_dates". Please include stacktrace.

Comment: @glibdud traceback added

Comment: Try restarting the ipython kernel. `datetime` is part of the standard library so my first suspicion is that you've accidentally shadowed the name in iPython in the past. I'm not sure how it'd give that specific error but these issues can manifest in unintuitive ways with iPython.

Comment: Never ever seen this happening, so a shot in the dark: Your python is broken because of an update or a messed up virtualenv (or most probably what roganjosh says)

Comment: @roganjosh restarting kernel did the trick. Thank you all for your input

Comment: What's frustrating is that I can't recreate the error in my iPython setup; I have no doubt that it was an iPython issue and you've now resolved it, but I'd like to be able to understand myself why this happened (the error is unusual because the name seemingly can be resolved) :/ Anyway, glad you've fixed it :)